# How can I get limited records from database using spring JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch records in batches from MySQL database. Initially I fetch records of 1st 10 rows, then next 10 rows, until I found every matched row.

I found one solution of limiting query, but It didn’t help me. 
Pageable p = PageRequest.of(offset, limit)

Here, if the offset is 0, and the limit is 10 then I got 10 records correctly. But, then if I applied value for offset other than 0, no rows were returned.

How can I use offset here? Or is there any other solution for this query? Please suggest if any.

Comment: Create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for clarity and add code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static PageRequest of(int page, int size)
```

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> page - zero-based page index, must not be negative.
> size - the size of the page to be returned, must be greater than 0.
> ```

Here the first parameter is index of `page` not `offset` and the second parameter is size of the page not `limit`. [Ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-)

**Example**: Suppose you have 30 documents. If you use page size as 10 then there will be 3 page total.

```
PageRequest.of(0, 10) -> offset 0 limit 10 -> will fetch first 10 document.
PageRequest.of(1, 10) -> offset 10 limit 10 -> will fetch 10 document after first 10 document.
PageRequest.of(2, 10) -> offset 20 limit 10 -> will fetch 10 document after first 20 document.
```

Comment: I was doing PageRequest of(0,10) , PageRequest of(11,10) etc which is wrong. Your solution works! thanks a lot.